# Отображение password, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, допустим есть модель с учетными данными

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Login{get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

И есть контроллер, и например мне надо вывести просто список в json учётных записей, но надо чтобы Password отображался в виде звездочек...есть какой-то атрибут для такого варианта?
То есть мне надо атрибут не для проверки вводимого значения, а для отображения...или тут надо мне руками писать в get;set; или на подобии этого?

Comment: У вас пароль не зашифрованный в базе хранится? Напишите метод который выдает строку из звездочек по длине входящей строки.

Comment: @Anamnian Пароль не зашифрованный, обычная строка.
Мне этот метод надо будет вставить в блок get?

Comment: а зачем вообще нужно тогда передавать пароль?

Comment: @yolosora 
Пароли хранятся в базе, запросил другой человек список учётных записей, и желательно чтобы пароли были не открыты, это я сократил модель, там 10+ свойств, просто другие важны, пароль конечно можно вообще не выводить, но так поставили задачу

Comment: При переводе из объекта записи в  бд в объект модели просто переводите тогда это поле  как указал @Anamnian, а вообще это конечно бессмысленно абсолютно, я бы в таком случае поле просто игнорил.

Comment: `Пароли хранятся в базе` - ошибка номер раз. `запросил другой человек список учётных записей` - не совершайте вторую ошибку, не передавайте пароли из БД никому.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо) там не будут передаваться пароли, это я так чтобы не углубляться сказал))

Comment: @Anamnian спасибо, сделал как Вы сказали, все ок теперь!

Comment: @Алексей , вы просто даете большой кусок информации потенциальному взломщику (если этот список доступен где-то помимо админки)- количество символов из которых состоит пароль. В результате чего в разы упрощается перебор пароля.